# How universal is the guillemet in written French?

Tags: usage, ponctuation

There's a discussion going on about the use of [Guillemet](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/115/67) in written French. The official view of l'Académie is pretty clear I think, but how widely is this reflected around the world?

Is it normal to use Guillemet instead of English style quotation marks when in Quebec for instance or other non-France French speaking countries?

In real world usage within France how much do people actually deviate from the official line in practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on the typographers. Some consider that using English quotes makes the text actually looks nicer, even though it is discouraged by the Académie (and the Imprimerie Nationale).

In the past, it was hard to typeset the guillemets, too. Modern programs replace quotes by guillemets automatically (or provide macros, like `frenchb` in LaTeX) which make it much easier to typeset them properly.

Answer (score 4):

Written publications in France (books, newspapers, academic journals, magazines) all use double guillemets as primary marks of quotation.

Answer (score 2):

In Belgium, we use guillemets as well as double quotes.

Comment: when you say 'as well', do you mean they're interchangeable, or that you could also use them together?

Comment: mmm right, the first case.

Comment: Is this the case for any kind of publication?

Comment: The newspaper _[La Libre Belgique](http://www.lalibre.be)_ uses English quotation marks “” more or less systematically (but one can still find _guillemets_ «» in some minor sections). However, I am pretty sure that the French-speaking publishing industry in Belgium uses _guillemets_ «» dominantly.

Answer (score 2):

In Canada, the guillemet is used.