# D'où vient l'expression « aller en boîte » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, étymologie

Il me semble que ça signifie « aller en discothèque ». Pourquoi est-ce qu'on utilise « boîte » pour désigner une discothèque ?

Comment: Avant de poser une question il faut regarder si la réponse ne peut pas se trouver facilement ailleurs, ce qui est le cas ici, voir le [wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/boite) pour le sens de boîte. Peut-être que formulée autrement la deuxième question aurait pu être acceptable, mais sans référence à l'anglais car le sens anglais n'est pas pertinent pour ce que tu veux demander.

Comment: À propos des meilleurs guillemets pour le français : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/115/is-it-necessary-to-use-guillemets-when-quoting-in-french-or-may-one-use-english

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Le mot « boîte » pour désigner un lieu s'employait pour désigner le lieu de travail et l'école/le lycée avant d'être employé pour désigner une « boîte de nuit » puis une « discothèque ». Je pense que l'emploi pour « discothèque » s'est fait à partir de « boite de nuit ». L'emploi de « boîte » pour désigner un lieu est apparu en 1860 (d'après le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* sld Alain Rey).