# La façon habituelle de dire « What does X mean? »

Tags: interrogative

Si je veux dire « What does 'cow' mean? », mais en français, je dirais « Que « vache » signifie-t-elle ? » ?

C'est la forme normale pour exprimer cette question ?

La question suivante m'est aussi venue à l'esprit :

« Signifie-t-elle »… j'ai choisi « elle » parce que je sais que « vache » est un nom féminin, mais si je ne sais pas si le mot est un nom ou pas, sans parler de masculin et féminin, je ne sais donc pas si le mot doit s'exprimer par « il » ou par « elle ». Que faire ?

(Des réponses en français ET en anglais me plairaient beaucoup.)

Comment: This form would be a little heavy on my mouth, so while speaking I always tend to use; *ç'est quoi un cow* , *ça veut dire quoi un cow* , *Qu'est-ce que c'est que ça un cow* .. Well, that's me (:

Comment: I removed one sub-question because it was unrelated to the main one (btw, here is [an answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/137/79)).

Comment: Why not ask the question in both language too, then?

Comment: Apathy, incompetence, hypocrisy, mortality...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que veut dire "cow" ?
Que signifie le mot "cow" ?
C'est quoi un "cow" ?
Qu'est-ce un "cow" ?
Qu'est-ce que c'est qu'un "cow" ?
Un "cow", c'est quoi au juste ?

*Bon sang mais c'est **bien sûr** !  La vache !*

Answer (score 4):

En français idiomatique et soigné on dit (et plus souvent on écrit) :

> Que signifie le mot « vache » ?

Au cours d'une discussion amicale :

> « Vache » ?… qu'est-ce que ça veut dire ?

Et en réponse à la question auxiliaire, comme il s'agit du *mot* « vache » (mais je dois préciser qu'il en serait de même pour l'*expression* « grosse vache »), le genre se perd et l'on s'attend à un pronom masculin — à défaut de pouvoir utiliser un pronom neutre comme *ça*, *ce*, *ceci* ou *cela*. Par exemple :

> « Vache » est-il considéré injurieux ?

Answer (score 3):

En français on dit :

> Ça veut dire quoi "cow" ?

Comment: En disant ceci, tu ne t'exprimes pas forcément en bon français (même si c'est compréhensible).

Comment: Bon français ou pas, « Ça veut dire quoi *xxxxx* ? » est probablement la forme la plus couramment utilisée en langage parlé.

Answer (score 0):

Les plus proches de la formulation anglaise:

> Que signifie "cow"? Que veut dire "cow"?

Qui se transforment en:

> Qu'est-ce que "cow" signifie? Qu'est-ce que "cow" veut dire?

Ces quatre formes sont correctes. "Vouloir dire" est moins formel que "signifier".

Notez que l'on ne peut pas traduire "What do you mean?" par "Que signifies-tu?" mais seulement par "Que veux-tu dire?"

Answer (score 0):

Salut,

Plusieurs variantes sont possibles, comme déjà évoqué. Il peut être important de distinguer langage formel et informel, ou langue parlée et langue écrite, en français.

Dans les commentaires précédents, on peut voir qu'une personne qualifie la variante 'ça veut dire quoi 'cow' ?' de mauvais français. Or, c'est sans doute l'une des variantes les plus utilisée dans la langue parlée. Qualifier de bon ou de mauvais des formules consacrées dans le langage courant est une forme de purisme et relève d'une linguistique prescriptive.

Les puristes, bien que trop restrictifs dans leur approche de la langue, ont tout de même un argument de poids. Vous pourrez toujours utiliser un langage formel dans la conversation ou dans une rave party, surtout si vous n'êtes pas de langue maternelle. Les gens apprécieront toujours cet effort et cela peut même donner du charme, alors qu'une personne de langue maternelle parlant avec un langage soutenu dans un contexte informel peut être perçue comme pédante ou arrogante.

Quelques exemples corrects (sauf la typographie) :

Que signifie 'cow' ?
Quelle est la signification de 'cow' ?
Que veut dire 'cow ?
Qu'est-ce que 'cow' veut dire ? / Qu'est-ce que veut dire 'cow' ?
Quel est le sens de 'cow' ?
Ça veut dire quoi 'cow' ? (langage parlé, informel)

Vous pouvez rajouter 'le mot' (Que signifie le mot 'cow' ?) dans ces exemples pour lever toute ambiguïté liée à l'utilisation d'un métalangage.

Votre suggestion initiale 'Que « vache » signifie-t-elle ? »' (qui serait similaire à 'Que « vache » veut-elle dire ?') est tout à fait compréhensible (voir juste si 'Vache' était personnifié), mais le fait que 'vache' soit utilisé comme sujet rend la phrase problématique, car c'est le mot ou le concept que vous chercher à comprendre et non la vache dans toute sa splendeur de mammifère. Il s'agit d'un problème lié à l'utilisation d'un métalangage. Vous pourriez éventuellement écrire 'Que signifie 'vache' ?' ou 'Que veut dire 'vache' ?'.

A titre de comparaison, vous pourriez imaginer la phrase correcte suivante :

'La beauté signifie-t-elle la même chose dans toutes les cultures ?' (tiré d'internet)

Dans ce cas, on voit que la beauté peut être sujet de 'signifier', car ce n'est pas tant le sens du mot à des fins d'apprentissage de la langue (métalangage terminologique), mais la signification profonde du mot (métalangage sémantique). On pourrait ainsi imaginer une question du type 'La vache signifie-t-elle la même chose dans toutes religions ?'. Dans le contexte qui nous intéresse ici, cette même question se formulerait mieux de la manière suivante :

'Le mot 'vache' signifie-t-il la même chose dans toutes les langues ?'.

J'espère que mon explication n'est pas trop obscure et permet de compléter le tableau des réponses. Je me suis un peu emballé peut-être.

Bien à vous,
Romanovitch