# Guillemets français et anglais

Tags: typographie

Pourquoi existe-t-il cette différence entre la typographie française et anglaise, à savoir « et » vs “ et ” ? Cette différence existe-elle dans les autres pays de la francophonie ?

La seule raison que je peux imaginer c'est que sur les machines à écrire, les guillemets anglais n'ont pas de sens d'ouverture ou de fermeture, ils sont donc moins précis (" et ").

Peut-on employer dans un texte français les guillemets anglais ? Par exemple, dans le cas où une citation doit contenir une autre citation, est-il possible d'utiliser les guillemets français conjointement aux guillemets anglais pour éviter le problème des guillemets emboîtés ?

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/115/is-it-necessary-to-use-guillemets-when-quoting-in-french-or-may-one-use-english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pourquoi existe-t-il cette différence entre la typographie française et anglaise, à savoir « et » vs “ et ” ?

Les raisons sont historiques. Ces differences ne concernent pas que ces deux pays, il existe bien d'autres variantes, en particulier les *» guillemets inversés «* utilisés en allemand et d'autres langues.

> Cette différence existe-elle dans les autres pays de la francophonie ?

Les règles de typographie peuvent varier un peu au sein de la francophonie, leur respect aussi...

> La seule raison que je peux imaginer c'est que sur les machines à écrire, les guillemets anglais n'ont pas de sens d'ouverture ou de fermeture, ils sont donc moins précis (" et ").

Ce ne sont pas exactement des guillemets anglais, dont les versions ouvrantes et fermantes sont distinctes, mais des guillemets dactylographiques, droits.

> Peut-on employer dans un texte français les guillemets anglais ?

Personne n'a été mis en prison pour ne pas avoir utilisé les « bons »  guillemets...

Les guillemets utilisés sont souvent ceux qui sont accessibles au clavier de la personne qui saisit le texte, donc les guillemets droits pour la plupart des claviers. Si un traitement de texte est utilisé et que la langue du document est définie, les guillemets sont souvent automatiquement convertis dans le bon format. En revanche, si le texte est saisi via une formulaire Web, les guillemets "droits" subsistent. C'est pourquoi beaucoup de contributions françaises sur FSE les utilisent. Entrer les guillemets français (doubles chevrons) est souvent compliqué et non intuitif.

> Par exemple, dans le cas où une citation doit contenir une autre citation, est-il possible d'utiliser les guillemets français conjointement aux guillemets anglais pour éviter le problème des guillemets emboîtés ?

Ce n'est pas recommandé par l'Imprimerie nationale (française), mais c'est le choix de nombreux journaux.

Comment: Voilà comment obtenir les guillemets dans Windows; code ANSI ; le guillemet gauche : tenir touche « alt » enfoncée puis taper « 0171 » au clavier numérique; le guillemet droit : même chose mais au lieu de « 0171 » taper « 0187 ». codes UNICODE : gauche : tenir « alt » enfoncée et taper « 174 »; droit : même chose mais taper « 175 ».

Comment: @user168676 Oui, mais comme je l'ai écrit, ça n'a rien d'intuitif. De plus, il faut un pavé numérique, ce qui est compliqué voire pas dispo sur un laptop, sans parler des smartphones... En général, sous Windows je reprogramme des touches de mon clavier ("AltGR" + "<" et "AltGR" + ">") avec msklc ou je fais juste un copier-coller...

Comment: La surprise est totale en lisant vos commentaires. J'ai un clavier qui n'a pas de pavé numérique mais il a cependant (un é, quoique pas de a accent grave directement) une touche pour les guillemets français, celui de gauche directement et celui de droite avec shift et cette même touche. Je suis incapable de comprendre pourquoi un clavier azerty n'a pas ça en 2018. Ou tous les Français s'achètent des claviers américains ? Ironiquement je n'ai il me semble jamais utilisé les guillemets français ailleurs que sur ce site ! Merci !

Comment: @juscogensprime Eh oui, l'agencement des claviers AZERTY en France est consternant. De manière surprenante, il n'existe pas de standard officiel, ce qui conduit à des incompatibilités, en plus du manque de caractères pourtant indispensables à une orthographe et typographie correcte (voyelles accentuées et c cédille en capitales, ligatures minuscule comme en majuscule, guillemets français...) Longtemps, la saisie au clavier a été méprisée et ignorée par les décideurs français mais ça a fini par changer.

Comment: Le Ministère de la culture a publié un [constat](http://www.culture.gouv.fr/Thematiques/Langue-francaise-et-langues-de-France/Politiques-de-la-langue/Langues-et-numerique/Les-technologies-de-la-langue-et-la-normalisation/Vers-une-norme-francaise-pour-les-claviers-informatiques) il y a deux ans et l'AFNOR a lancé un consultation. Le futur standard devrait être [publié dans quinze jours](https://norminfo.afnor.org/norme/pr-nf-z71-300/interfaces-utilisateurs-dispositions-de-clavier-bureautique-francais/113295).

Answer (score 1):

Voici ce que donne Wikipédia, mais sans référence pour l'instant :
Les guillemets droits doubles ou simples (" " et ' ') sont souvent employés en dactylographie, en raison d’une fréquente absence de touches correspondant aux guillemets français sur les claviers de machines à écrire et d’ordinateurs. Cet usage est cependant déconseillé par l’Académie française.

complement added 02/09/18

Voilà une raison assez convaincante tirée de [Wikipedia en anglais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark)

Une raison plausible n'a rien à voir avec les claviers de machine à écrire et date de bien avant ces avancées historiques dans la technologie de l'écriture. Elle est donnée en quelques mots ici, voir le lien pour un grand nombre de détails.
Pendant longtemps avant le XVIII siècle les guillemets consistaient de deux marques arrondies vers l'extérieur et ils étaient utilisés ainsi dans toute l'Europe, jusqu'au XVIII siècle, où la forme et l'usage des guillemets a commencé à se particulariser dans les diverses régions de l'Europe de l'ouest; selon certains chercheurs le guillemet français a évolué de la forme en 2 apostrophes à la forme en 2 chevrons sous l'impulsion d'un soucis de préserver dans l'ensemble des signes du langage des signes qui auraient été suffisamment différents des apostrophes ou virgules.